# How to do overload in Scala?

Tags: scala, overriding, h2o

I'm very new to Scala and H2O. I know there is extend class in Scala. But what I want to do is have two classes with same name but different parameter type.

I hope when I call test, if I put either a String or a Double parameter into it. The class will recognize the Data type I put into it and run the right function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can parametrize your class to make it 'generic':

```
class test[T](a: T, b: T) extends MRTask {}
```

so when you'll use this class in real life type `T` will be determined automatically based on your input.
For `test("str", "str" )` , `T` will be `String`

If you want to limitat your type with `String` and `Double` you can not use both this bounds in same time. You have to find common parent class for those two. It's `Any`. It will not help you a lot.

For ex. you need to implement some method that depends on type should apply different behaviour. For this purpose I recommend you to use pattern matching.

```
  case class test[T <: Any](a :T, b: T) { 

    def foo (): T = {
      a match {
        case d: Double => d
        case s: String => s
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you explain a little more to me? test is the class name, what about T? I can't understand how you parametrized the class? Really appreciate that

Comment: Just read documentations about generics: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/generic-classes.html

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for keep asking...in the documentation I can not understand how it T is bound to a real type?

Comment: Thanks for your patience

Comment: Can I do class test[T <: String, T <: Double](a: T, b: T) extends MRTask {}

Comment: You hero! Let me try! Thanks!

Comment: I update my question. can you see problem with my code? it still doesn't work.. Thanks

Comment: I update my question here. Can you help me take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442536/how-to-parametrize-class-and-implement-method-depends-on-type