# How to parametrize class and implement method depends on type in Scala

Tags: scala, parameters, match, h2o

This is what I tried. Depends on what does user put into the function I want to add String or Double to new Chunk.

```scala
package org.apache.spark.h2o.utils

import water.fvec.{NewChunk, Frame, Chunk}
import water._
import water.parser.ValueString

class ReplaceNa[T >: Any](a: T) extends MRTask{
  override def map(c: Chunk, nc: NewChunk): Unit = {
    for (row <- 0 until c.len()) {

        a match{
             case s: ValueString if(c.isNA(row)) => nc.addStr(s)           
             case d: Double      if(c.isNA(row)) => nc.addNum(d)

      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I got error

```
 error: value outputFrame is not a member of Nothing
          pred.add(new ReplaceNa(3).doAll(1, pred.vec(4)).outputFrame(Array("s"), null))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you mean `nc.addStr(s)` and `nc.addNum(d)`.

Comment: Sorry maybe my code is wrong, but what I want to do is to match a with String and Double. If a is String then addStr(a). If a is Double then addNum(a).

Comment: At this point in the code the compiler knows that `s` (not `a`) is a string and `d` (not `a`) is a double.

Comment: I modify the code but still same error. I updated my post

Comment: I want to let the code compare the input parameter a with String and Double to figure out a's data type

Comment: Really appreciate your patience

Answer (score 2):

I have several comments:

- check for NA outside the switch branch
- you are missing non-NA case hence you are generating vector which is shorter than input vector (i expect you would like to generate the same length vector)

Regarding generics, you need to provide type specialization. For example, something like the following snippet:

```
class ReplaceNA[T](val value: T)(implicit add: TAdd[T]) extends MRTask[ReplaceNA[T]] {
  override def map(c: Chunk, nc: NewChunk): Unit = {
    for (row <- 0 until c.len()) {
      // Replace NAs by given value
      if (c.isNA(row)) {
        add.addValue(nc, value)
      } else {
        // Do something with default value
        nc.addNA()
      }
    }
  }

}

trait TAdd[T] extends Serializable {
  def addValue(nc: NewChunk, value: T)
}

object TAdd extends Serializable {
  implicit val addDouble = new TAdd[Double] { def addValue(nc: NewChunk, value: Double) = nc.addNum(value) }
  implicit val addFloat = new TAdd[Float] { def addValue(nc: NewChunk, value: Float) = nc.addNum(value) }
  implicit val addValueString = new TAdd[ValueString] { def addValue(nc: NewChunk, value: ValueString) = nc.addStr(value) }
}
```

Comment: Hi Michal, Thanks for your response. i have this error after modify my code.java.lang.RuntimeException: ReplaceNA.Ljava/lang/Object;: Serialization not implemented